# Storyboard animation on an element within a TabItem does not stop when changing tabs

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard, tabcontrol, tabitem

I have a `TabControl` with dynamically created `TabItems` that each contain a `Border` element that I need to animate (make the border flash Yellow to orange) when a property on a viewmodel is greater than zero, via Data Binding, but remain black if the value is zero.  Each `TabItem` has it's own instance of the viewmodel, so the property value could be different for each `TabItem`, therefore the animation should only be activated on the appropriate `TabItem` (i.e. each `TabItem` is a `UserControl` that contains several `Border` elements, one of which I wish to animate triggered by a Property value in the `UserControl`s viewmodel).

I have several similar elements, so I am using a `MultiDataTrigger` to check for a `tag` on the element, as well as check the property value (via a converter).

I can successfully animate the `BorderBrush` when selecting a `TabItem` where the property value is greater than zero, but when I then select a `TabItem` where the property value is equal to zero, the animation should stop, but does not.  I am also changing the `BorderThickness` and the `Margin`, and these settings return to the normal settings as expected, but the animation does not stop.

I am using a `Style.Trigger` to apply the animation, and a converter to convert the property's value from an `int` to a `boolean` (true if greater than zero, and false if zero).

Here is my xaml code (from app.xaml):

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}" x:Key="JobFilterExternalBorder">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="3"/>
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2,0,1,0.8"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <!-- Add Data Trigger to identify if filter is UnprocessedParts and value is > 0, and animate border to imitate a flashing border -->
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Tag}" Value="IsUnprocessed"/>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding UnprocessedQty, Converter={StaticResource ConvertNonZeroToBoolean}}" Value="true"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="6"/>
                    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,-2,-1,-1.2"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Name="FlashStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource AnimationFlashYellowToOrange}">
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="FlashStoryBoard" />
                    <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="FlashStoryBoard"/>
                </MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

And my `Storyboard`:

```
    <Storyboard x:Key="AnimationFlashYellowToOrange" Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush" RepeatBehavior="Forever" Duration="0:0:1" FillBehavior="Stop">
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Yellow" />
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5">
                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Orange" />
                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

And the view to which this is being applied:

```
    <Border Name="UnprocessedQtyBorder" Tag="IsUnprocessed" Style="{StaticResource JobFilterExternalBorder}" >
    </Border>
```

I can confirm that the `MultiDataTrigger` is working fine because the `BorderThickness` and changes back to the normal thickness when the `MultiDataTrigger` becomes false when selecting a `TabItem` where the property value is equal to zero.  It's just the animation that does not stop.

**I have tried:**

- Adding `StopStoryboard` to the `MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions`
- Adding `RemoveStoryboard` to the `MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions`
- Including `FillBehaviour="Stop"`
- Adding a second `MultiDataTrigger` to start a new Storyboard that sets the `BorderBrush` to black
- Changing the order of the `Style` settings to have the `MultiDataTrigger` before the standard property settings
- Searching the internet for any other examples that might point me in the right direction

I need to have the Storyboard animate the border continuously while the offending element is on screen, so I have included the `RepeatBehavior="Forever"` property

I am following MVVM design pattern and would prefer to avoid having code-behind, but I'm not zealous about it.

I have been struggling with this all day and have not made any progress, so this is my last hope.

**EDIT:**
I suspect the `MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions` are never executed in order to stop the `Storyboard`, so an additional question must be asked; Is it even possible to stop a Storyboard in this manner?  Can the `MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions` be triggered to execute some other way?

**EDIT2:**
I have created a sample VS solution to demonstrate the effect I am seeing.  The solution can be found on GitHub [here](https://github.com/paularmy42/TabControlWithAnimationExample)

**EDIT3:**
This is what is currently happening:
[image]

When returning to "Tab 1", the animation should stop.

Comment: Is this Border inside each  TabItem? Is the border outside the TabControl and should animate depending on the TabItem selected?

Comment: The Border is inside each TabItem.  I have edited the question to include this detail.

Comment: I am still unclear about the end result you wish to achieve, Do you want to animate the Selected TabItem only? And when the selection changes you want the unselected item animation to stop? If so, you can add the IsSelected property of the TabItem to the MultiDataTrigger conditions.

Comment: @Insane: Yes.  The element only needs to be animated when the TabItem it belongs to is the selected tab.  There may be multiple tabs with this element where the conditions for animating are met, and multiple where the conditions are not met, so when changing tabs, if the conditions are not met, the animation must stop.

Comment: @Insane:  I tried using '<Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=TabItem}}" Value="true"/>' to find the TabItem, but I receive an error saying the source cannot be found.

Comment: @Insane: I have published an example solution to Github [link:](https://github.com/paularmy42/TabControlWithAnimationExample)

Comment: The behavior seems unusual. Storyboards for all the borders in all the tabs are triggered when one TabItem condition is satisfied. Your code looks fine. As a workaround I would suggest that you keep the default BorderThickness in the style from 3 to 0. <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}" x:Key="JobFilterExternalBorder">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>